# How to find out that a method is Long Method?

Tags: code-metrics

How can I find out that whether a method is considered a long method or not.  Because, it may possibly contain 3 lines of code or it may contain 300 lines of code.  If it contains 3 lines of code then it is not a long method, but if it contains 300 lines of code then definitely it is a long method.  My question is how can someone find out that whether it is a long method or not.  Is there any algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Uncle Bob suggests a method should have no more than 4 lines. Only in rare cases you could disregard this rule.

[functions](http://cleancoders.com/codecast/clean-code-episode-3/show)

Comment: Uncle Keith suggests that this is too small a number.  The vast majority of Java methods in the world (excepting accessors) exceeds this number.  This includes most methods in textbooks and in production code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many existing metrics packages that measure the size of methods (e.g., the [Eclipse Metrics plug-in](http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/)).  The number of lines that constitutes a "long" method varies by language and by various authors' opinions (e.g., see this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540244298) on OO metrics).